# can we get the browser history using sessions and cookies in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

Is there any inbuilt function to track the browser history or any other way,
it will b very helpful to me and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

No in-built function takes care of it as of now. It's fairly simple to do it yourself.

You can store a cookie in the response.

```
response = HttpResponseRedirect('/path/to/redirect/')
response.set_cookie("key":"value")
```

and track the behaviour going forward.

Example,
If you wanna count visits,

```
response.set_cookie("visits":0)
```

Then add a line of code in your js, to keep updating this counts for every visit and add this visits count to the user profile in the login/logout view.

Check this [link](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/cookie.html) it has a basic implementation of the same.

Otherwise, you can use [google analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/) too.